# OnClickListener in Fragment

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have: `public class FeedApp extends Fragment  {`

```
 .....   
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                          ....
    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity(), feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
....
```

In my custom Adapter `FeedListAdapter` I have a `button "Show/hide"`.
If I click I can see the description (TextView) otherwise I hide the description (TextView).

```
public static void toggle_contents(View v){

        switch(v.getId()){

         case R.id.showHide:
           description.setVisibility( description.isShown() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE );

       break;
    }
```

My Adapter:

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Content> feedItems;
    private TextView title;
    private TextView description;
    TextView showHide;

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Content> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);       
        title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        showHide= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hideShow);

        Content item = feedItems.get(position);
        title.setText(item.getTitle());
        description.setText(item.getDescription());         
        return convertView;


    }
```

My big problem is how and where I have to implement the onClick();

I tried in my adapter but it doesn't work.
Somebody can suggest me something???Thx

Comment: Post your adapter code.

Comment: I put my Adapter....

Comment: Why is `showHide` a TextView? I thought it's supposed to be a button.

Comment: It will become an image  (\/ /\) but now it is only to test that the function works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code in your adapter:

```
private SparseArray<Boolean> mVisibleDesc = new SparseArray<Boolean>();

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Content item = feedItems.get(position);

    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if (convertView == null) {
        // Inflate item layout
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);
        // Set the description
        final TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        description.setText(item.getDescription());
        description.setTag(position);
        // Set the listener
        TextView showHide = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hideShow);
        showHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Get the position of this item
                Integer position = (Integer) description.getTag();
                if (mVisibleDesc.get(position)) {
                    // true
                    description.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mVisibleDesc.put(position, false);
                } else {
                    // false or null (not yet set)
                    description.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mVisibleDesc.put(position, true);
                }

            }
        });
    } else {
        // ConvertView not null, set the description
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        description.setText(item.getDescription());
        description.setTag(position);
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(item.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}
```

A few notes about it:

- Since ListViews re-use the layouts you have to manually save which items have their description hidden and which don't.
- In addition to the above, you also need to make the `description` know which item it's on, so the listener can know which one to hide/show.
- This code has some repetition, it can be reduced by using a ViewHolder pattern (Google). That will also increase the efficiency of your whole adapter.
- Remove the global variables: `description`, `title` and `showHide` in your adapter. They should stay local in your `getView` method.

Reply if you have any problems with this.

Comment: Thx for your support. Integer position = (Integer) description.getTag(); it is always null.why?

Comment: I just tried to assign to position =description.getId(); the method function but it applied the showHide for all elements of the ListView....;(

Comment: @user880386 `getTag` should work, I've checked the code. Make sure you copied it correcly and the notes on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If onClick() is not working for you, you can hard code the method call in the button declaration. Just go to the button's XML declaration in the layout xml file, and add the following line:

```
android:onClick="toggle_contents"
```

That should probably do the trick. And remove "static" from the method if it does not impede anywhere else. It works in simple Activity, it should too in Fragment.

Comment: Did you remove the "static" keyword before trying?

Answer (score 0):

put `android:onClick="toggleContents"` inthe declaration of button in your XML file, and then create 
`public void toggleContents(View v)` method in activity to wich your fragment is attached